# store value from sqlite android to radio button

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

in my application, user can do CRUD operation. 
when user input data, there are 13 radio group (selected value are string format). After completely input data, user can save it into sqlite. My questions is, when user clicked edit button, i want to know what code to returned the selected radio button (user checked before) can checked automaticly.

code in MainActivity :

```
rg1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg1);
     rg1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
     {
         public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
             switch(checkedId){
                 case R.id.rb_large:
                     palm_size="1";

                     // do operations specific to this selection
                 break;

                 case R.id.rb_average:
                     palm_size="2";

                     // do operations specific to this selection
                 break;

                 case R.id.rb_small:
                     // do operations specific to this selection
                     palm_size="3";

                 break;

                 case R.id.rb_vsmall:
                     // do operations specific to this selection
                     palm_size="4";

                 break;

             }
}
     });
```

code for getting String and display in Edittext..

```
 protected void onResume(){

            super.onResume();
            i=getIntent();
            mark=i.getStringExtra("mark");
            //jika berasal dari edit, maka tampilkan

            if(mark!=null){
                //id=i.getStringExtra("id");
                et_estate.setText(i.getStringExtra("estate_name"));
                et_manuring.setText(i.getStringExtra("manuring_block"));
                et_year.setText(i.getStringExtra("year"));
                et_record.setText(i.getStringExtra("record_date"));

                et_bare.setText(i.getStringExtra("bare_soil"));
                et_legume.setText(i.getStringExtra("legumes"));
                et_lightgrass.setText(i.getStringExtra("light_grasses"));
                et_fern.setText(i.getStringExtra("ferns"));
                et_competitve.setText(i.getStringExtra("competitive"));
                et_remarks_competitive.setText(i.getStringExtra("competitive_weed"));

                //rg1=i.getStringExtra("yellowing");

                et_remarks.setText(i.getStringExtra("remarks"));

                id_assm=i.getStringExtra("id_assm");

            }


        }
```

How to restore the selected radio button by this code into radio group (rg1)?
Help me on it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the `id` of your `RadioButton` instead of the `value`
Then you can restore the selected radio button by

```
intent.putExtra("idOfYourSelectedRadioButton", idOfYourSelectedRadioButton);
```

and

```
rg1.check(i.getIntExtra("idOfYourSelectedRadioButton", R.id.idOfDefaultRadioButton));
```

Comment: still can't.. let me know another code please.. i stuck on it

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question properly but looks like you want to  check the radio button programmatically. May be this will help

onResume :

```
rg1.check(R.id.rb_small)
```

where R.id.rb_small may be the checked value you want to restore

Comment: what i mean is how to restore selected value in radio group . the value saved into sqlite, when user clicked edit button, automaticly value from radio group was selected on user first  input @nishan khadka

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
         switch(checkedId){
             case R.id.rb_large:
                 palm_size="1";

                   String rb_large="true";
                 // do operations specific to this selection
             break;

             case R.id.rb_average:
                 palm_size="2";
                    String rb_average="true";
                 // do operations specific to this selection
             break;

             case R.id.rb_small:
                 // do operations specific to this selection
                 palm_size="3";
                String rb_small="true"
             break;

             case R.id.rb_vsmall:
                 // do operations specific to this selection
                 palm_size="4";
                String rb_vsmall="true"
             break;

         }
```

these string send to second activity and then check which string is true, those string is true means radio button is checked, then in oncreate you use setChecked(true) method to automatically true